# Marionette not clearing models and collection on destroy()

Tags: backbone.js, memory-leaks, marionette

I'm looking at moving from vanilla Backbone to Marionette and, just like it was for Backbone, my first concern is to make sure I don't have memory leaks since I'm building a one page application.

Using Backbone debugger, I can see that when I change the view displayed in my LayoutView region, the HTML is indeed destroyed but the model and/or collection remain in the memory forever.

First, here's my PostController code:

```
var PostController = Marionette.Object.extend({     
    showOne: function(post_cd){
        // layoutView
        var postView = new PostView();

        // Create data containers
        var comments = new Comments(); // This is a Backbone.Collection
        var post = new Post(); // This is a Backbone.Model

        // Create subviews (compositeView)
        var commentsView = new CommentsView({collection: comments, model: post});

        // Render the compositeView in the layoutView when displaying the layoutView
        postView.on('before:show', function(region, view, options){
            this.showChildView('comments', commentsView);
        });

        // Data init.
        post.fetch();
        comments.fetch();

        // Show the view on the main region.
        // app.layout is another LayoutView binded to <body>
        app.layout.showChildView('main', postView); 
    }
});
```

Next up, my UserController code:

```
var UserController = Marionette.Object.extend({
    showOne: function(userCd){
        var user = new User({user_cd: userCd});

        // Marionette.ItemView
        var userItemView = new UserItemView({model: user});

        // Fetch the user
        user.fetch();

        // Show the view on the main region
        app.layout.showChildView('main', userItemView); 
    }
});
```

Pretty simple, I just create a model/collection and an associated view and then switch them around in my "main" region.

Here are my very simple views:

First, UserItemView (used in UserController):

```
var UserItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: "<a href='#post/48' id='goToPost'>Go to post 48.</a>",

    events:{
        "click #goToPost": "goToPost",
    },

    goToPost: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        app.testRouter.triggerMethod('post:show', 48);
    }
});
```

My compositeView "CommentsView" (used in PostController):

```
var CommentsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    childView: CommentItemView,
    childViewContainer: "#comments_list",

    tagName: 'div',
    id: 'comments',
    template: '<ul id="comments_list"></ul><a href="#" id="goToUser">Go to user 20.</a>',

    ui: {
        userLink: '#goToUser'
    },

    events:{
        "click @ui.userLink": "goToUser"
    },

    goToUser: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        app.testRouter.triggerMethod('user:show', 20);
    }
});
```

Those are the results from the Backbone Debugger:

1) Opening the app on the Posts page:

Views:
[image: Views1]

Models:
[image]

As expected, 3 models. One post (model) and 2 comments (collection).

Collections:
[image]

2) Navigating to my "user" page:

Views:
[image]

The old views are correctly removed and the new one added.

Models:
[image]

My 3 old models are still present! Along with my new one.

Collections:
[image]

Even though this page doesn't use any collection, the old one from the Post page is still here.

Am I missing something ? Am I supposed to manually clear those in onDestroy() ? If so, how ? I tried delete and setting to null, but none of those worked.

I also checked the memory differences using the Heap snapshots after clicking between the page for a while, it indeed goes up infinitely.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would any collection or model be destroyed automatically just because a view was removed from the DOM?

Comment: I don't know about marionette, but your controllers are keeping references to these collection/models even after view is deleted right?

Comment: @ivami, the model shouldn't be destroyed as in removed from the server, but it should be removed from memory.

TJ, They are created in the local score with var so when the view is destroyed, they are no longer referenced and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was being trolled by Backbone debugger, it seems to keep instances alive so you can continue monitoring/checking them out.
Marionette explorer has the same flaw.

I disabled both of them and went hunting for my backbone objects in my Heap profiles and found that it's behaving as it should.

For those with the same issue, to find backbone objects in the heap profiles, don't search for "backbone", "model" or whatever, search for "child".
All backbone objects are under "child", because of how the controller works.